# Difference in output of program in c for scanning character value due to space .(In Dev c++)

Tags: c, integer, char, scanf, space

Problem: space role in nested switch

Even if `i` is `char`, why does code work?

After making `i` an `int` min file is formed i.e. no output.

Here my program goes:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    char num, i, choice;
    int fact, f = 1;
    int n1, n2, n3;
    int c1, c2, calsum;

    printf("Enter the operation you want to perform:\n 1.Factorial\n 2.Calculator\n 3.Greater of three\n 4.Fibonacci series\n 5.Star Pattern\n");
    scanf("%c", &num);

    switch (num) {
        case '1':
            //Factorial
            printf("Enter the number to find factorial of :\n");
            scanf("%d", &fact);

            for (i = 1; i <= fact; i++) {
                f = f * i;
            }

            printf("Factorial of %d is %d", fact, f);
            break;

        case '2':
            //Calculator
            printf("Enter your choice:\n a.Addition\n b.Subtraction\n c.Multiplication\n d.Division\n");
            scanf("%c",&choice);
            printf("Enter two numbers:");
            scanf("%d%d", &c1, &c2);

            switch (choice) {
                    case 'a':
                        //Addition
                        calsum = c1 + c2;

                        printf("Addition is %d",calsum);
            }
            break;

        case '3': 
            //Find greatest NO.
            printf("Enter three numbers :");
            scanf("%d%d%d",&n1,&n2,&n3);

            if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3) {
                printf("%d is greatest", n1);
            }
            else if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3) {
                printf("%d IS GREATEST", n2);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d is greatest", n3);
            }
            break;

        default: printf("Exit");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm linking the output of my program:

1. With space before %c and
2. Without space.

[image]

Description:

While scanning the choice character when space is given before `%c`, the scanning operation is performed. While without space the scanning is skipped and display further statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: `"%c"` reads a character, no matter what it is, like the newline left in the buffer after the first operation. `" %c"` skips leading whitespace before reading.

Comment: Why is your code double spaced?  It's makes it harder to read.

Comment: What's the question?  It seems you describe two behaviors which is consist with out space in format strings work.

Comment: Always check return value of I/O operations like `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.  Use an enum to name your menu options instead of the comments `enum { FACTORIAL, CALCULATOR, GREATEST } num`.  It's a good idea to minimize scope of variables.  `n1` through `n3` are only used in menu 3 so introduce a block and move the variables there.  Look out for duplication.  For instance in menu 3 it's the same print statement (or should be) so maybe write a function to determine to max value and just print that (once)?

Comment: Note that if someone enters the three numbers 27, 27, 17 for the 'greatest' test, your code will erroneously report that 17 is the greatest.  You need to worry about recalcitrant users who don't enter three different numbers.